# GitHub Pages - Failed to load CSS of webpage

Tags: html, css, github

I just complete my *Google Homepage project* from *The Odin Project* tutorial. I've uploaded my **index.html** & **style.css** file into GitHub, and follow the steps from *The Odin Project* to publish my web project from GitHub repository.

But my [My GitHub repo Web project](https://rogueape.github.io/google-homepage/) has failed to load the CSS file, while my web page in `[codepen io][2]` work completely fine and they both use the same coding.

Anyone can help me solve the problem? This is [my GitHub Web project page](https://github.com/RogueApe/google-homepage).

Sorry if my English is poor and I'm a complete newbie to coding and GitHub.

Comment: this is the link "https://codepen.io/rogueape/full/abBYPdB" to my web page project at codepen io that works just fine.

Comment: There is no link to the CSS file? https://nimb.ws/mqrLRH

Comment: Codepen works because there is no need of linking in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link your css file in your html in order to load the styles.

```
<head>
    <title>RogueApe's Google Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! Much appreciated!! 
I'm new to coding and this <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> help me clear my mind and I've learn a new code! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you forgot linking your css file.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! Much appreciated!! I'm new to coding and this <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> is new to me, and now its help clear my mind and had solve my problem! Thanks buddy!!